# Query & Plot 1 Million datapoint using Hibernate + Highcharts

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, highcharts

I have a table with 5 million records & need to run a query which will return minimum 1+ million records.

I tried to implement querying part to return 1 million records only using Spring Boot + Hibernate. It takes **5mins for querying 60K** records for hibernate to query & map entity. But, from **SQL developer it takes 0.03secs** only. for querying 1M records, getting timeout error.

I cannot have Pagination, since i am going to plot result in chart (HighCharts). I need entire data for chart datasource.

Please suggest how to handle Querying of such big data & rendering plot

Comment: You can try to use query.setReadOnly(true).list(); Hibernate wil not put entity into context and will work faster. But you will lose persitence with this entity.

Comment: Of course you can set setFetchSize(60000) - query. setFetchSize(60000).list()

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan, You do not have to load all the data at once. Please check the example of lazy loading concept: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading